# Android Getting Co ordinates

Tags: java, android, touch, coordinates

A little problem for you but Break point for me during the development of an application.

I have a background image of Layout in which I have a Zip(Cloth zip) in the middle and at the top of image.

I want to do the following some things:

> - get coordinates of center-point(that is the starting point of Touch) of that image where that zip exists.
> - On moving the finger down, getting the changed coordinates.
> - X coordinate should be constant after getting the mid point,     means the user can only drag on the middle of the screen vertically.

So badly waiting for an expert response.

Answer (score 0):

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics); 
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
int center1 = (width/2) - (aspected touchable area you need);
int center2 = (width/2) + (aspected touchable area you need);

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
int x = (int)event.getX();
int y = (int)event.getY();
switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
 //Logic for Zip motion
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
//Logic for Zip motion
 }
return false;
}
```

Comment: Please add a little info about why this is correct.

Comment: DisplayMetrics help out getting dimensions of the device. Then You can find out the inner centeral width that will be between (center1 and center2). 
onTouchEvent you can perform any action you want to perform on touch down etc. you can save previous state and then perform any action if new state has been changed.

Maybe this is helpfull for you